# Obtain XML section in string VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services, soap

I'm using vb.net and I have a WebService that sends me a SOAP envelope as a result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tfd:Answer DateAnswer="2014-05-02T17:19:38" Certificate="30001000000100000801" version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm already able to obtain individual values from inside de XML like DateAnswer or Certificate but now I need to receive the whole section with the "Answer" tag for later storage. In other words this:

```
<tfd:Answer DateAnswer="2014-05-02T17:19:38" Certificate="30001000000100000801" version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Is there a simple way to obtain this whole section in a string? I've looked it up but I sense I'm not using the correct key words for the search.

Comment: Why don't you simply use "Add Service Reference" to access the service? See [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/). You shouldn't have to play with XML.

Comment: but what I need is a whole section of the result that comes from using that webservice not a part of the webservice itself.

Comment: That would get you the entire result, and you could do what you want with parts of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I used to solve my problem.

```
Dim Xns As XNamespace = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
mySection = myXMLDocument.Descendants(Xns + "Body").First().FirstNode.ToString()
```

"mySection" contains the string I need.